# Append rowcount for all files in a directory to filename before extension

Tags: mv, wc

I am trying to write a one-liner to append a row count to the filename of each file in a directory before the extension. I thought I could do this with wc -1 but I am struggling to get it in a variable to append to the filename.

```
for file in *.txt ;do rowcount="wc -l < $file" mv $file ${file%.txt}_$rowcount.txt; done
```

Comment: Almost there, try `for file in *.txt ;do rowcount=$(wc -l < "$file") ; mv "$file" "${file%.txt}_$rowcount.txt"; done`